# jQuery click remembers how many times I clicked and firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

I have a button that toggle what is visible- links or form with input text. Problem occurs when I click it fast multiple times, input of a search is just blinking like crazy, fading in and out for every single time I clicked the button and I would like to prevent it from firing so many times.

How can I do that ??

```
   $("#search-button").on("click", function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       e.preventDefault();

       $("#search-form").fadeToggle(800);

       if (links.css('visibility') === 'hidden')
           links.css('visibility', 'visible');
       else
           links.css('visibility', 'hidden');

   });
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, provided links are completely useless and unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deactivate the click handler until the animation is over, then reactivate it.

```js
var toggleSearch = function(e) {
  $("#search-button").off("click"); // When the click is received, turn off the click handler

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#search-form").fadeToggle(800, function() {
    $("#search-button").on("click", toggleSearch); // When the animation is finished, turn the click handler on again
  });
/*
  if (links.css('visibility') === 'hidden')
    links.css('visibility', 'visible');
  else
    links.css('visibility', 'hidden');
*/
}

$("#search-button").on("click", toggleSearch);
```

```css
#search-form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="search-button">search-button</button>
<form id="search-form">

</form>
```

Comment: kindly explain the downvote. It's working, so what's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Thx, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Outside of going down the rabbit hole of learning about observables or debouncing, [you can probably steal David Walsh's debounce function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

*The Debouncer*:

```
// Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked, will not
// be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
// N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
// leading edge, instead of the trailing.
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Implementation:

```
var myDebouncer = debounce(function() {

    // Put your original code here

}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myDebouncer);
```

You can now debounce any other operation in your app as well by passing it through this.